# Create index on timestamp delivered by JSON - incorrect datetime value

Tags: mariadb, date-formatting, mariadb-10.3

I constantly retrieve JSON data from some API and put that data into a MariaDB table.
The JSON ships with a timestamp which I'd like to place an index on, because this attribute is used for querying the table.

The JSON looks something like this (stripped):

```json
{
    "time": "2021-12-26T14:00:00.007294Z",
    "some_measure": "0.10031"
}
```

I create a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_table (
    my_json JSON NOT NULL,
    time TIMESTAMP AS (JSON_VALUE(my_json , '$.time')),
    some_measure DOUBLE AS (JSON_VALUE(my_json , '$.some_measure'))
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

`my_json` holds the entire JSON snippet, `time` and `some_measure` are virtual columns properly extracting the corresponding JSON values on the fly.

Now, trying to add an index on the TIMESTAMP attribute:

```sql
CREATE INDEX some_index ON some_table (time);
```

This fails:

```
SQL Error [1292] [22007]: (conn=454) Incorrect datetime value:
'2021-12-26T14:00:00.007294Z' for column `some_db`.`some_table`.`time` at row 1
```

How can I add an index on that timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution that works for me.
Changes are:

- use `STR_TO_DATE()` to create a valid `DATETIME` from the JSON timestamp
- make the generated (virtual) column `PERSISTENT`
- use data type `DATETIME` instead of `TIMESTAMP`

So the new code looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_table (
    my_json JSON NOT NULL,
    time DATETIME AS (STR_TO_DATE((JSON_VALUE(my_json , '$.time')), '%Y-%m-%d%@%T%.%#%@')) PERSISTENT,
    some_measure DOUBLE AS (JSON_VALUE(my_json , '$.some_measure'))
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE INDEX some_index ON some_table (`time`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that converting a string (the JSON timestamp) to a TIMESTAMP is non-deterministic because it involves server side settings (sql_mode) and timezone settings.

Indexing virtual columns which are non-deterministic is not supported.

You would want to use a VARCHAR data type instead and index that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_table (
    my_json JSON NOT NULL,
    time VARCHAR(100) AS (JSON_VALUE(my_json , '$.time')),
    some_measure DOUBLE AS (JSON_VALUE(my_json , '$.some_measure'))
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

You should be able to create your index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX some_index ON some_table (`time`);
```

You can still query time because MariaDB automatically converts DATETIMEs if used against a VARCHAR:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM some_table
WHERE time > '2008-12-31 23:59:59' + INTERVAL 1 SECOND;
```

The query will use the index:

[image: EXPLAIN of the SELECT query]

Comment: I tried that, but MariaDB will still throw a warning like `Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2021-12-24T14:00:00.007294Z'`. That solution does work, but I preferred to find a cleaner solution that will not give any warnings, and I found a way using the `STR_TO_DATE()` function, see below